# Converting multiple character columns to expressions in R dataframe

Tags: r, function, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |       Calc1       | Calc2             |
   1    |    2    |   4     | Column1 + Column2 | Column3 + Column1 |
   7    |    6    |   3     | Column1 + Column2 | Column3 + Column1 |
   9    |    9    |   10    | Column1 + Column2 | Column3 + Column1 |
```

Column1, Column2, Column3 are "numeric". Calc1 and Calc2 are "character".

I also have a list of column names called ColNameList and contains c("Calc1", "Calc2").

I would like to apply some function which converts the character values to actual R expressions. The columns that I would like this function to apply to must be informed by the list of column names (i.e. check the list of column names in ColNameList, then match those column names to columns in the dataframe and then apply the function to convert character to expression.)

My expected output is this:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Calc1   | Calc2   |
   1    |    2    |   4     |    3    |    5    |
   7    |    6    |   3     |    13   |    10   |
   9    |    9    |   10    |    18   |    19   |
```

I have tried:

```
df1 <- df1(apply(df1[,ColNameList],2, function(x) eval(parse(text=df1$x))))
```

I've had a look around and have found similar questions but I can't seem to reverse engineer other solutions to fit my scenario; particularly the requirement to have the function only apply to columns listed in ColNameList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution which accepts a list of column names, and uses that to identify columns in a given dataframe, and then converts the character values in the given columns to actual R expressions. This solution is useful as it can be generalised to accept different expressions rather than just sums.

Here's the solution:

```
Column1 <- c(1,7,9)
Column2 <- c(2,6,9)
Column3 <- c(4,3,10)
Calc1 <- c("Column1 + Column2", "Column1 + Column2", "Column1 + Column2")
Calc2 <- c("Column3 + Column1", "Column3 + Column1", "Column3 + Column1")

df <- data.frame(Column1,Column2,Column3,Calc1,Calc2)

ColNameList <- c("Calc1", "Calc2")



df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(across(ColNameList, ~ eval(str2expression(.))))
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `eval` + `str2expression`

```
transform(
  df,
  Calc1 = eval(str2expression(Calc1)),
  Calc2 = eval(str2expression(Calc2))
)
```

gives

```
  Column1 Column2 Column3 Calc1 Calc2
1       1       2       4     3     5
2       7       6       3    13    10
3       9       9      10    18    19
```

---

**Update**

If you have a function `f` to be applied over columns, here might be one option. Assuming `f` is given as below

```
f <- function(x, y) x + y^2
```

when we run

```
as.data.table(df)[
  ,
  c(cols) := lapply(
    .SD[, cols, with = FALSE],
    function(x) {
      do.call(
        f,
        unname(.SD[, unlist(strsplit(unique(x), "\\s\\+\\s")), with = FALSE])
      )
    }
  )
][]
```

and we will get

```
   Column1 Column2 Column3 Calc1 Calc2
1:       1       2       4     5     5
2:       7       6       3    43    52
3:       9       9      10    90    91
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but, I need to use ColNameList to identify the columns which the function is applying to, rather than hard coding each of the column names.

Answer (score 1):

In data.table it just works:

```
library(data.table)
setdT(df)

df[, c1 := eval(parse(text = Calc1))]
```

If you want both in one go, then:

```
a[, `:=` (c1 = eval(parse(text = Calc1)), c2 = eval(parse(text = Calc2)))]
```